# get_matching_blocks() is ignoring some blocks if it matches first with blocks that come later

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

Here's the python code -

```
import difflib
x = "abxcd"
y= "cdab"
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y)
for block in s.get_matching_blocks():
    a=block[0:]
    if a[2]>0:
        m=a[0]
        n=a[0]+a[2]
        print (x[m:n])
```

It prints out only 'ab' and ignores 'cd'.
But I want it to print out both 'ab' and 'cd'.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean 'ab' and 'cd' ?

Comment: Yes! sorry, my bad. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) of `get_matching_blocks()`

> Return list of triples describing non-overlapping matching subsequences. Each triple is of the form (i, j, n), and means that a[i:i+n] == b[j:j+n]. The triples are monotonically increasing in i and j.

So as per your inputs `"abxcd"` and `"cdab"` it searches for 'a' in 'cdab' which is at position 2(starts from 0) and then 'b' in position '3' which is the last postion of the second string. By the time it reaches 'x' second string iteration has already been completed.

```
>>> s=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,  "abxcd","cdab")
>>> s.get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=0, b=2, size=2), Match(a=5, b=4, size=0)]
```

Lets take another example where `x="abxcd"` and `y="abcd"` you will get the result as `ab, cd`. Initially it searches for 'a' in 'abcd' which is at postion 0 and 'b' in position 1 and similarly for 'c' and 'd' in position 2 and 3 of string2

```
>>> s=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,  "abxcd","abcd")
>>> s.get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=2), Match(a=3, b=2, size=2), Match(a=5, b=4, size=0)]
```